# OpenGL viedo rendering on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, pjsip

I am working on video calling in **PJSIP** and i am facing an issue with rendering the video using **openGL**.
I am able to see the real time video but in **green tint** color, I presume that it is an issue with openGL texture.
I dont have any knowledge on openGL so i am pasting some openGL code snippets which I use in my application.
Please tell me where I am going wrong, all I need to do is somehow remove the green tint in the video.

Below is the code to the best of my knowledge

//YUV toRGB Vertex Shader

```
attribute vec4 position; 
attribute vec2 textureCoordinate; 
varying vec2 coordinate; 

void main() 
{ 
  gl_Position = position;
  coordinate = textureCoordinate.xy; 
}
```

//YUV to RGB Fragment Shader

```
uniform sampler2D SamplerY; 
uniform sampler2D SamplerUV; 
varying highp vec2 coordinate; 

void main() 
{ 
  mediump vec3 yuv; 
  lowp vec3 rgb; 
  yuv.x = texture2D(SamplerY, coordinate).r; 
  yuv.yz = texture2D(SamplerUV, coordinate).rg - vec2(0.5, 0.5); 

  rgb = mat3(1,             1,      1, 
             0,       -.21482, 2.12798,
             1.28033, -.38059,      0) * yuv; 

  gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1); 
} 



static void uninitialize_gl_buffers(struct ios_stream *strm)
{
  TRACE_((THIS_FILE, "uninitialize_gl_buffers"));
  glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &strm->frameBufferHandle);
    glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &strm->colorBufferHandle);
}

static void initialize_gl_textures(struct ios_stream *strm)
{
  TRACE_((THIS_FILE, "initialize_gl_textures"));
  glGenTextures(1, &strm->lumaTexture);
  glGenTextures(1, &strm->chromaUTexture);
  glGenTextures(1, &strm->chromaVTexture);
}

static void uninitialize_gl_textures(struct ios_stream *strm)
{
  TRACE_((THIS_FILE, "uninitialize_gl_textures"));
  if (strm->lumaTexture) {
    glDeleteTextures(1, &strm->lumaTexture);
    strm->lumaTexture = 0;
  }
  if (strm->chromaUTexture) {
    glDeleteTextures(1, &strm->chromaUTexture);
    strm->chromaUTexture = 0;
  }
  if (strm->chromaVTexture) {
    glDeleteTextures(1, &strm->chromaVTexture);
    strm->chromaVTexture = 0;
  }
}

static void allocate_gl_textures(struct ios_stream *strm,
                                 int frameWidth, int frameHeight)
{
  TRACE_((THIS_FILE, "allocate_gl_textures %dx%d", frameWidth, frameHeight));
  // Y planes (init)

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glGenTextures( 1, &strm->lumaTexture );
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, strm->lumaTexture);

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  //glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, frameWidth, frameHeight, 0,
               GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

  // U-planes (init)
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glGenTextures( 1, &strm->chromaUTexture );
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, strm->chromaUTexture);

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, frameWidth/2, frameHeight/2, 0,
               GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

  // V-plane (init)
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    glGenTextures( 1, &strm->chromaVTexture );
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, strm->chromaVTexture);

  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, frameWidth/2, frameHeight/2, 0,
               GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
}

static void update_gl_textures (struct ios_stream *strm)
{
  //const pj_uint8_t *buffer = (const pj_uint8_t *)strm->buf;
  const pj_uint8_t *buffer = (const pj_uint8_t *)strm->frame->buf;
    pj_uint32_t width  = strm->size.w;
  pj_uint32_t height = strm->size.h;

  //TRACE_((THIS_FILE, "update_gl_textures %dx%d (%d)", width, height, buffer));

  // Y planes (update)
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, strm->lumaTexture);
  glUniform1i(uniformLocations[UNIFORM_Y], 0);

  glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0,
                  width,            // source width
                  height,            // source height
                  GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                  buffer);

  // U-planes (update)
  buffer += width*height;
  width >>= 1;
  height >>=1;

  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, strm->chromaUTexture);
  glUniform1i(uniformLocations[UNIFORM_U], 1);

  glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0,
                  width,            // source width
                  height,            // source height
                  GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                  buffer);

  // V-planes (update)
  buffer += width*height;
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, strm->chromaVTexture);
  glUniform1i(uniformLocations[UNIFORM_V], 2);

  glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0,
                  width,            // source width
                  height,            // source height
                  GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                  buffer);

}
```

Comment: rgb = mat3(1,             1,      1, 
             0,       -.21482, 2.12798,
             1.28033, -.38059,      0) * yuv;

Comment: This looks like a likely culprit - try changing to another colour.

Comment: i tried changing few values but of no use I couldnt get the natural effect.